# C++ constructor & destructor order

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

I am trying a code about base class and member construction and destruction and I am confused about some order of constuctor and destructor,
the output of this code is:

```
Base1 constructor
Member1 constructor
Member2 constructor
Derived1 constructor
Member3 constructor
Member4 constructor
Derived2 constructor
Derived2 destructor
Member4 destructor
Member3 destructor
Derived1 destructor
Member2 destructor
Member1 destructor
Base1 destructor
```

See the first four line,
but  I fell the order should be

```
Base1 constructor
Derived1 constructor
Member1 constructor
Member2 constructor
```

Anyone can give me some explain？

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
ofstream out("order.out");

#define CLASS(ID) class ID { \
public: \
  ID(int) { out << #ID " constructor\n"; } \
  ~ID() { out << #ID " destructor\n"; } \
};

CLASS(Base1);
CLASS(Member1);
CLASS(Member2);
CLASS(Member3);
CLASS(Member4);

class Derived1 : public Base1 {
  Member1 m1;
  Member2 m2;
public:
  Derived1(int) : m2(1), m1(2), Base1(3) {
    out << "Derived1 constructor\n";
  }
  ~Derived1() {
    out << "Derived1 destructor\n";
  }
};

class Derived2 : public Derived1 {
  Member3 m3;
  Member4 m4;
public:
  Derived2() : m3(1), Derived1(2), m4(3) {
    out << "Derived2 constructor\n";
  }
  ~Derived2() {
    out << "Derived2 destructor\n";
  }
};

int main() {
  Derived2 d2;
} ///:~
```

Comment: +1 for providing a full minimal code example reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Constructors are called upwards in the hierarchy:

```
- base class member objects
- base class constructor body
- derived class member objects
- derived class constructor body
```

The output is correct.

Let's simplify your code:

```
struct BaseMember
{
   BaseMember() { cout << "base member" <<endl; }
};
struct Base
{
   BaseMember b;
   Base() { cout << "base" << endl; }
};
struct DerivedMember
{
   DerivedMember() { cout << "derived member" << endl; }
};
struct Derived : public Base
{
   DerivedMember d;
   Derived() { cout << "derived" << endl; }
};

Derived d;
```

When `d` is created, it will first create the `Base` part. Before it enters the constructor body, all member objects are initialized. So `BaseMember` is the first object initialized.

Next, the constructor of `Base` is entered.

Before, the constructor of `Derived` enters, member objects of `Derived` are initialized, so `DerivedMember` is created, next `Derived` constructor is called.

This happens because when you enter the constructor body of a derived class, base classes and member objects must be completely initialized.

**EDIT** As Matthieu pointed out, the order in which the member objects are initialized is specified by the order in which they appear in the class definition, not the order in which they appear in the initializer list.

Comment: Note 1: for `virtual` bases, things get a little weird. Note 2: the order in which the bases and attributes are listed is of no import, it all depends on the order they appear in the class definition.

Comment: @MatthieuM. what do you mean listed?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Oh you mean the initializer lists? Yes, that's true.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: ah yes, initializer list. It's a typical mistake for beginners to think it has any influence.

Comment: @user1279988 The gentleman deserves an answer tick. And so do many people who have answered your questions thus far.

Answer (score 2):

Constructor of the class executes later than constructors of its fields. Constructor of base class and all its members executes earlier than constructor of derived class and its members.

Answer (score 1):

Well the initialisation done in the initialisation list happens before the body of the Derived1 constructor, so you see the output for m1 and m2 first.

As a more complete answer, what happens is this: first base sub-objects are constructed, then members are constructed in order of their declaration in the class (not their order in the initialisation list), then the constructor body is executed. Destruction happens in reverse order.

In this case, when you construct a Derived2, it first goes to construct the Derived1 sub-object. This in turn involves first constructing the Base sub-object, so it does that first. It then constructs the members of Derived1, executes the body of the Derived1 constructor, constructs the members of Derived2 and finally executes the body of the Derived2 constructor. Hence the observed output.

Answer (score 1):

This is simply because `m1` and `m2` are initialized in the initialization list of the `Derived1` constructor. Everything in the initialization list is constructed before the body of the constructor is entered.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following program which will make your idea clear!

```
#include<iostream.h>
class A
{
public:
  A()
    {
    cout<<"\nI am the base class constructor!";
    }
  ~A()
    {
    cout<<"\nI am the base class destructor!";
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
  B()
    {
    cout<<"\nI am the derived class constructor!";
    }
  ~B()
    {
    cout<<"\nI am the derived class destructor!";
    }
};

int main()
  {
  B obj;
  return 0;
  }
```

The output of the above program will be as follows..

I am the base class constructor!

I am the derived class constructor!

I am the derived class destructor!

I am the base class destructor!

I think this explains and clarifies your query about the order of invocation of the constructors and destructors.